# Reverse breakdown

Tags: semiconductor-physics

What happens to a PN junction after the biasing voltage reaches the reverse breakdown voltage ?That is what exactly happens to that immobile majority charge Carriers ?Do they also contribute to the large reverse current which is due to the generation of free electrons due to breaking of covalent bonds?Do the majority charge carriers simply diffuse away?

Comment: I’m confused. What is an immobile charge carrier?

Comment: The depletion region is composed of  immobile charge carriers.That's what I meant .What happens to the depletion region a huge reverse current is flowing?In many books it is mentioned that depletion region gets damaged. But what exactly happens to the charge carriers  present inside the depletion region when the huge reverse current flows? How do they get damaged? Do they also get drifted along with the reverse current and so destroy the depletion region?